# Can I replace comma separated string with specific pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace this

```
192.168.1.100,192.168.1.101,192.168.1.102
```

to

```
server 192.168.1.100;server 192.168.1.101;server 192.168.1.102;
```

with sed command in linux.

Comment: At least put some effort in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with two substitutions, first to insert the "server " piece (that's "server" followed by a space) just after all occurrences of start-of-string or comma, and second to replace all occurrences of comma or end-of-string with a semicolon.

```
sed -E 's/(^|,)/&server /g; s/(,|$)/;/g;' <<<'192.168.1.100,192.168.1.101,192.168.1.102';
## server 192.168.1.100;server 192.168.1.101;server 192.168.1.102;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in three steps:

1. Replace commas with semicolumns
2. Add the terminal semicolumn
3. Replace each IP-address terminated with semicolumn by the same address with the `server` prefix.

`sed 's/,/;/g ; s/$/;/ ; s/([0-9.]*;)\;/server \1/g'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple `sed` solution using a single substitution:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),\?/server \1;/g'
```